# Orient SQL - Filter result set using WHERE?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orient-sql

I've got a bit of a semantic question about Orient SQL queries.

Take for example this very simple graph:

```
v(#12:1 User) --> e(#13:1 FriendOf) --> v(#12:2 User)
```

In other words, a given User with an rid of #12:1 is friends with another user with an rid of #12:2.

To get the friends of user #12:1, one might express this in Orient SQL like so:

```
SELECT EXPAND(both("FriendOf")) FROM #12:1
```

This query would return a result list comprised of the User with rid #12:2.

Now lets say I want to filter that result list by an additional criteria, like say a numeric value ("age"):

```
SELECT EXPAND(both("FriendOf")) FROM  #12:1 WHERE age >= 10
```

The above query would filter the CURRENT vertex (#12:1), NOT the result set. Which makes sense, but is there a way to apply the filter to the EXPAND(both("FriendOf")) result rather than the current vertex? I know I can do this with gremlin like so:

```
SELECT EXPAND(gremlin('current.both("FriendOf").has("age",T.gte,10)')) FROM #12:1
```

But the above does not seem to make use of indexes (at least not when I ask it to explain). For very large data sets, this is problematic.

So is there a proper way to apply a WHERE statement to the resulting data set?

Thanks !

Comment: This seems to work too, but doesn't use indexes either:
SELECT EXPAND(both("FriendOf")[age >= 10]) FROM #12:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... is there a way to apply the filter to the EXPAND(both("FriendOf")) result rather than the current vertex?

The simple answer is to embed your basic "SELECT EXPAND ..." within another SELECT, i.e.

```
SELECT FROM (SELECT EXPAND(both("FriendOf")) FROM #12:1) WHERE age >= 10
```

By the way, on my Mac, the above took .005s compared to over 2s for the Gremlin version. There must be a moral there somewhere :-)

Comment: @nightrise - I don't really understand why the call to EXPAND is necessary in the SELECT FROM (SELECT EXPAND(_) ....) ... statement. Do you?  In any case, the OrientDB documentation on EXPAND that I've been able to find  is very unimpressive; if you have the same impression, maybe one of us should create a documentation ER at https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues ...)

Comment: I think the difference is that without EXPAND, you basically just get the record id (@rid). With EXPAND, you're basically telling it to fetch the actual record data by traversing the link. For example, for a given User vertex "Bob" with "FriendOf" edges connecting it to other User vertices, the "Bob" vertex document has a list of RIDs which represent the links to the edges (or vertices in case of "lightweight" edges). Does that make sense? And yes, I tend to use the Orient SQL where possible as it does seem faster in many cases!

Comment: I should add that sometimes you don't want to traverse the link, simply to retrieve the rid or check for it's presence. I've personally made use of this myself, and it makes a big difference in performance (especially when using lightweight edges) when you don't need the entire dataset.

Comment: @nightrise - As the OrientDB documentation explains, EXPAND(_) has two uses -- "When used on a collection field, it unwinds the collection in the field ... When used on a link (RID) field, it expands the document pointed by that link." In your query, I believe the first case applies.  What I don't understand is why both() doesn't do the "expansion".  In fact, I'm inclined to say it's either a bug or misfeature.

Comment: Actually I think its the second case (expands the document pointed by that link). EXPAND is applied to both("FriendOf") which is an edge/link. It traverses it and "resolves" the link (rid reference) to its whole document. I dont think its a bug, it makes sense to have that since you dont necessarily want to resolve it -- sometimes you just want to retrieve the rid.

Comment: @nightrise - Unfortunately there are some important differences between different versions of OrientDB, and these may be confusing the discussion.  However, I think I've worked it out, at least in the case of OrientDB 2.1.7. `select both("FriendOf") from <someclass>` returns a result set, each "result" essentially being a list of Vertex RIDs, one result per instance of <someclass>.  If <someclass> is specified as an RID, the `select both(_)` statement still returns a result set with the same structure, only this time there's just one "result" (corresponding to the RID specified in the query).